# My dropdown list would not drop down

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I tried to use php to create a dropdown list populated by a SELECT query but it would not dropdown. Here is my php script

```
<?php
require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');
@mysqli_select_db($dbc,"test");
$query = "SELECT category_id, category_name FROM forum_category ORDER BY category_name";
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if(!$result)
{
    echo "query error: " . mysqli_error($dbc);
}
//  while($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result))
//  {
//      echo "<p>$row[0] $row[1]</p>\n";    //this works
//  }

echo "<td bgcolor=\"#E6E6E6\"";
echo "<strong>Category:</strong>";
echo "<select name=\"category\">";

while($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
//      echo "<p><option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</option></p>\n"; 
    echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</option>"; 
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
echo "</select>";
echo "</td>";
?>
```

The query worked (the commented while loop outside the dropdown list displayed 15 records). But the dropdown list only showed one category_name and would not dropdown. Can someone help me figure out the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Place `mysqli_close($dbc);` after `echo "</td>";`

Comment: Are you sure `$row[0]` and `$row[1]` don't contain html entities? For example, if row 0 contained a quote (') it would close the value attribute...

Comment: Thanks guys. I moved mysqli_close($dbc); after echo "</td>"; but nothing changed. $row[0] and $row[1] do not contain quote.

Comment: Make sure you have data in both rows. I tested your code and got no problems. You're also missing `<table></table>` tags. Either add them or remove `echo "<td bgcolor=\"#E6E6E6\"";` and `echo "</td>";` this could very well be the issue.

Comment: You mean you had it worked without any modification? This is really strange. I tried adding <table></table> as well as removing <td /td> but nothing changed. I do have data in both rows, as I said in original post that the while loop outside the list (commented) showed 15 records with both rows. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below. I've outlined what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

You can either remove both `echo "<td bgcolor=\"#E6E6E6\"";` and `echo "</td>";`

which is the reason why your data is not showing.

Or, add the appropriate `<table></table>` tags.

Plus this `echo "<td bgcolor=\"#E6E6E6\"";` should be `echo "<td bgcolor=\"#E6E6E6\">";` there was a missing `>` so that alone is breaking your `<td>`.

So in order to have the proper table syntax do:

***Sidenote:*** I added `. "\n"` in order to get clean and well-aligned HTML source.

```
<?php 

require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');
@mysqli_select_db($dbc,"test");
$query = "SELECT category_id, category_name FROM forum_category ORDER BY category_name";
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo "query error: " . mysqli_error($dbc);
    }

        echo "<table>" . "\n";

        echo "<tr>" . "\n";

        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#E6E6E6\">" . "\n";

        echo "<strong>Category:</strong>" . "\n";
        echo "<select name=\"category\">" . "\n";

            while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</option>" . "\n";

                    }

    echo "</select>" . "\n";

    echo "</td>" . "\n";

        echo "</tr>" . "\n";

    echo "</table>" . "\n";

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

---

**Edit:** (Try this) since I don't know what your full code looks like.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="form1_handler.php">
<?php 

require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');
@mysqli_select_db($dbc,"test");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$query = "SELECT category_id, category_name FROM forum_category ORDER BY category_name";
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo "query error: " . mysqli_error($dbc);
    }

        echo "<table>" . "\n";

        echo "<tr>" . "\n";

        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#E6E6E6\">" . "\n";

        echo "<strong>Category:</strong>" . "\n";
        echo "<select name=\"category\">" . "\n";

            while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</option>" . "\n";

                    }

    echo "</select>" . "\n";

    echo "</td>" . "\n";

        echo "</tr>" . "\n";

    echo "</table>" . "\n";

mysqli_close($dbc);

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I copied your script but it didn't work. This is very strange because the query works. As I said in a previous comment, adding <table></table> and removing <td /td> did not change anything.

Comment: You're welcome. `$row[0]` should correspond to `category_id` and `$row[1]` to `category_name`, correct? Plus, try and remove `ORDER BY category_name` but doubt that will make a difference - I tested your code with a similar table I have and everything checked out. I wouldn't have posted this unless I was 100% sure it worked. @user3334714

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, $row[0] corresponds to category_id and $row[1] corresponds to category name. I removed "ORDER BY category_name" but the problem remained.

Comment: Is there any other code I should be made aware of? Because this should work, exactly as shown. If you have more codes like `<form></form>` tags, JS etc., I need to know. Plus, your DB connection is in fact `mysqli_` and not `mysql_`, correct? @user3334714 Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything and `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()` and try and get rid of the @ symbols. You're suppressing possible errors.

Comment: I have <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="form1_handler.php"> </form> outside the above code. I use mysqli_ not mysql_ and the query runs correctly without error. Thanks.

Comment: That may be the reason. The `<select></select>` are outside the form tags. @user3334714

Comment: @user3334714 Reload my answer and look under **Edit**, since I don't know what your full code looks like.

Comment: Thanks Fred. I tried your new code but only a submit button appeared.

Comment: Fred: I found the problem, it is my Firefox browser. The code works in Chrome. I really appreciate your help. Without your saying that the code worked for you, I would have given up trying. Thank you very much Fred.